# How do I detect the change in text without changing the focus in QPlainTextEdit Class?

Tags: c++, qt

With this Qt construct,

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qplaintextedit.html

I have `tabChangesFocus`

but what if I want to detect a change on the input without having to tab to detect it?  I want to change and then be able to hit save, no tabbing or focus changing necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [textChanged()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qplaintextedit.html#plainText-prop) signal to do this.

This is a piece of code you can slightly modify to fit the requirements.

```
connect(ui->textBox, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this, SLOT(DoSmth()));
```